# Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x10b708d38) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x10b708978).And not able to see my data in collection view

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am try to get data and display in my collection view.But when i try to display.I am getting some error.And not able to display.And also please look my json structure below.It look like under my data only i need to get the type name and have to display in my collection view.

This is my first ios.Please help me out what problem i have.

Here my code :

```
import UIKit

class popVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {


    var accessToken = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyIkX18iOnsic3RyaWN0TW9kZSI6dHJ1ZSwiaW5zZXJ0aW5nIjp0cnVlLCJnZXR0ZXJzIjp7InNvY2lhbF9saW5rcyI6e319L"




    var arrCol :NSMutableArray=[]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         self.jsonParsingFromURL()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }
// collection view delegate

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrCol.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: colvwCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! colvwCell


         cell.lblCell.text = arrCol[indexPath.section] .valueForKey("type") as? String

        return cell
    }



    func jsonParsingFromURL () {
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://someurl/data?accessToken=\(accessToken)")
        let dataTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            print("done, error: \(error)")

            if error == nil
            {

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                    self.arrCol=(try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSMutableArray

                    print(self.arrCol)

                }

            }


        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }



}
```

Here my json structure :

```
   {
  "success": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "_id": "56c8d71999e4d5cd268d9eca",
      "type": "park",

    },
    {
      "_id": "56cbeb01425448492ad528ce",
      "type": "medical",


    },
    {
      "_id": "56cbeb9d6deb684f2a140e5e",
      "type": "home",

    },
    {
      "_id": "56cbec2beff2bf552a0447c4",
      "type": "kitchen",

    },
    {
      "_id": "56cbed2e1c856c672a302ce4",
      "type": "bloare",

    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The JSON is doubtless a dictionary (represented by `{}`), but it isn't valid

Comment: @vadian  so, does, i need to change any in code

Comment: First of all post a valid JSON (the square brackets are not properly balanced)

Answer (score 0):

To get the array for the `data` key and check simultaneously if the value for key `success` is 1 use this

```
if error == nil {
  do {
    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
    if let dataArray = json["data"] as? [[String:String]], success = json["success"] as? Int where success == 1 {
      self.arrCol = dataArray
      print(dataArray)
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // update here the UI.
      }
    }
  } catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
  }
}
```

and declare `arrCol` as a native Swift Array

```
var arrCol = [[String:String]]()
```

Comment: That replaces the whole block starting with `if error == nil` in the `jsonParsingFromURL()` method. In the dispatch block call the method to reload the collection view.

Comment: i am getting error ` Cannot assign value of type '[[String : String]]' to type 'NSMutableArray' ` in this line `self.arrCol = dataArray`

Comment: I updated the answer. After receiving the data and populating the array you have to call a method to reload the collection view, that means `update the UI`.

Comment: no, still i am not able to see any data in my collection view,Its fully blank

Comment: does i assign correct value in my ` cellForItemAtIndexPath `

Comment: I'm not familiar with collection views, but with my suggested syntax you can write `arrCol[indexPath.section]["type"]` rather than `arrCol[indexPath.section] .valueForKey("type") as? String`. Did you add the `reloadData()` method called on the collection view instance? Is `cellForItem...` called at all?